# How to write to user input in powershell

Tags: powershell

In my profile script for powershell I want to write to user input, so that when i start powershell I will already have something in my input and have only to press enter.
I need something like "write-input".

I have already tries "echo", "write-input".

Comment: What's your use case? This sounds potentially dangerous.

Comment: I user powershell always to execute the same commands so I wanted to have the most used already typed in as i start powershell

Comment: Why not make them functions and/or aliases in your profile then? Think about it: you're trying to save a handful of keystrokes *only* when starting PowerShell. I start a new PowerShell console once every few *days* - pre-typing something is not a significant "savings" unless you're constantly killing & restarting PowerShell, which seems wasteful to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
$defaultvalue = "This is the default value"
$a = read-host -Prompt "$defaultvalue (enter)"
if (!$a) {$a = $defaultvalue}
write-host "the value is now $a"
```